# I want to have the + and = sign to appear in middle

Tags: c++

I have problems with finding a way to assure the `+` and `=` sign to be in middle or where they are supposed to be; like if it contains 3 rows it is in second row, if 5 rows it is in third and if 2 rows it is in second.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int Sizer = 0, Sizec = 0, first[10][10], second[10][10], sum[10][10];
    cout << "Enter the number of rows for array: ";

    // input
    cin >> Sizer;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns for an array: ";
    cin >> Sizec;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the elements of first Array";
    cout << endl;

    // nested loop execution and input
    for (int c = 0; c < Sizer; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << "Enter elements of array [" << c + 1 << "]" << "[" << d + 1 << "]: ";
            cin >> first[c][d];
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the elements of second Array";
    cout << endl;

    // nested loop and execution
    for (int c = 0; c < Sizer; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << "Enter elements of array [" << c + 1 << "]" << "[" << d + 1 << "]: ";
            cin >> second[c][d];
        }
    }

    // outputting a sum
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sum of Arrays: ";
    cout << endl;

    // loop execution and sum
    for (int c = 0; c < Sizer; c++)
    {
        cout << "[";

        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << first[c][d];

            if (d != Sizec - 1)
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "]";

        if (Sizer == Sizer / 2 + 0.5)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "   ";
        }

        cout << "[";
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << second[c][d];
            if (d != Sizec - 1)
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "]   ";
        // output sum
        cout << "[";
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            sum[c][d] = first[c][d] + second[c][d];
            cout << sum[c][d];
            if (d != Sizec - 1)
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "]";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I want the output to look something like this

```
[2 3 5] [2 5 0] [4 8 5]
[1 2 3]+[4 8 1]=[5 10 4]
[1 1 3] [4 1 1] [5 2 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your test for the middle line:

```
if (Sizer == Sizer / 2 + 0.5)
```

that'll never be `true` if `Sizer` is greater than `0`, you want something like:

```
if (c == Sizer / 2)
```

Edit: Because `c` is your row count and you're testing when it's equal to the middle row (`Sizer / 2`).

Comment: can you say why and is it the same about the =

Comment: i just meant to ask for why the first eq will never be correct and second will.Thanks for the help

Comment: Can someone explain me this

Comment: @Pual Evans if c is the row count can you say me what is Sizer

Comment: @ZackRaez Read the code - it's what's input to the prompt: `"Enter the number of rows for array: "`